# Saxon CE and XQuery? Documentation indicates no XQuery, Examples otherwise?

Tags: xslt, xpath, xquery, saxon

Saxon CE, a javascript implementation of the popular XSLT, has documentation that indicates Saxon-CE has had XQuery support removed.

However, an [example](http://www.saxonica.com/ce/demos/tour/tour.xsl) in the Saxon-CE [documentation](http://www.saxonica.com/ce/user-doc/1.1/index.html#!samples/tour) has was looks like to me to be XQuery in several "select"'s.

Specifically...

```
<!-- Set up the empty board -->
<xsl:variable name="empty-board" as="xs:integer*" select="for $i in (1 to 64) return 0"/>
```

and ...

```
<!-- integer in range 0..63 -->
<xsl:sequence select="for $i in 1 to 64 return if ($i = $square + 1) then $move else $board[$i]"/>
```

As a beginner with XSLT/Xpath/XQuery in general, and mostly recently Saxon-CE, I'm confused. The above looks like XQuery to me, but the documentation indicates that Saxon-CE does not support XQuery.

Is the above really XQuery?
Does Saxon-CE actually support XQuery?
Is the above something else entirely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[XSLT 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/)** and **[XQuery 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/)** utilize **[XPath 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/)**, which is what you are recognizing as **XQuery** in the code above.

- The above code is **XSLT 2.0**, not XQuery.
- Saxon-CE does not support XQuery, but by supporting **XSLT 2.0** it inherently supports **XPath 2.0**.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense! Now that I know what I'm looking at, I've found the section in the XPath 2.0 specification that describes the for-expression. Thanks!